# A problem of Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ invertible matrices such that

$$BAB^{-1}=A^{-1}$$

Suppose that $A^{-1}+B$ is invertible. Is there an expresion for $(A^{-1}+B)^{-1}$ in function of $A$ and $B$ ?

My goal is find an expression of $(A^{-1}+B)^{-1}$ as a linear combination of $I,A,B,A^{-1}, B^{-1}$

Comment: $\left(A^{-1}+B\right)^{-1}=\left(AB^{-1}+I\right)^{-1}B^{-1}$

Comment: I want a better expression

Comment: You can always play around and replace $I$ with $BB^{-1}$, but without a goal it's hard to know what a "better expression" is.

Comment: @charlus My goal is find an expression of $(A^{-1}+B)^{-1}$ as a linear combination of $A,B,A^{-1}, B^{-1}$

Comment: Another (imperfect) option: it's possible to write $(A^{-1}+B)^{-1}$ as an infinite sum of powers of $A$ and $B^{-1}$: $\left(AB^{-1}+I\right)^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(-AB^{-1}\right)^n$ which is defined when $\lVert AB^{-1}\rVert < 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write $(A^{-1}+B)^{-1}$ as a linear combination of $I,A,B,A^{-1},B^{-1}$ in general. E.g. when
$$
A=\pmatrix{2\\ &2\\ &&\frac12\\ &&&\frac12},
\ B=\pmatrix{0&0&0&-1\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0},
\ (A^{-1}+B)^{-1}
=\pmatrix{
1&-1&\frac12&\frac12\\
1&1&-\frac12&\frac12\\
-\frac12&\frac12&\frac14&-\frac14\\
-\frac12&-\frac12&\frac14&\frac14},
$$
the $(1,2)$-th entries of $I,A,B,A^{-1},B^{-1}$ are all equal to zero. Hence $(A^{-1}+B)^{-1}$ does not lie inside their linear span because its $(1,2)$-th entry is nonzero.

However, we do have
$$
(A^{-1}+B)^{-1} = (I-B^2)^{-1}(A-B)
$$
when $I-B^2$ is invertible. Since $BAB^{-1}=A^{-1}$, we have $ABAB^{-1}=I$ and in turn $AB=BA^{-1}$. Hence
$(A-B)(A^{-1}+B)=I-B^2$ and we obtain the above equality. In theory, $(I-B^2)^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $B^2$ (whose coefficients depend on $B$). Hence $(A^{-1}+B)^{-1}$ is a linear combination of $B^{2k}A$ and $B^{2k+1}$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one:
\begin{align*}
(A^{-1}+B)^{-1}&=(BAB^{-1}+B)^{-1}\\
&=(BAB^{-1}+BBB^{-1})^{-1}\\
&=(B(A+B)B^{-1})^{-1}\\
&=(B^{-1})^{-1}(A+B)^{-1}B^{-1} \\
&= B(A+B)^{-1}B^{-1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need an expresion for $(A+B)^{-1}$

Comment: Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity.

Comment: A nice compilation of identities...thank you

Comment: My goal is find an expression of $(A^{-1}+B)^{-1}$ as a linear combination of $A,B,A^{-1}, B^{-1}$